# Retuning statement with dblink gives error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-returning, database-link

I have created a table with generated identity column .script below
CREATE TABLE "TABLESAMPLE"
(    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
"TID" NUMBER(5,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE
) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED

```
i am inserting data to the db from a remote database using dblink like below. Here when i return the id i get the below error on (RETURNING )
 
 Insert into  TABLESAMPLE@dblink1(DESCRIPTION) values('1') RETURNING tid INTO v_tid_return;

*Cause:    RETURNING clause is currently not supported for object type
           columns, LONG columns, remote tables, INSERT with subquery,
           and INSTEAD OF Triggers.

I am using oracle sql developer to run the script. can you please help
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanitory: you can't use the `RETURNING` clause on a remote table over a database link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says:

> **Cause**: RETURNING clause is currently not supported for object type columns, LONG columns, **remote tables**, INSERT with subquery, and INSTEAD OF Triggers.

Table over a database link *is* a remote table.

`Mike` is user accessed via database link:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create table tablesample
  2  (description varchar2(2),
  3   tid number generated always as identity
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tablesample(description) values ('LF');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tablesample;

DE        TID
-- ----------
LF          1
```

Back to `scott` (it contains database link to user `mike`):

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_tid number;
  3  begin
  4    insert into tablesample@dbl_mike (description) values ('XY')
  5    returning tid into l_tid;
  6
  7    dbms_output.put_line('Returned value = ' || l_tid);
  8  end;
  9  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22816: unsupported feature with RETURNING clause
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Would a synonym in my own schema help? Unfortunately, not:

```
SQL> create synonym scott_tablesample for tablesample@dbl_mike;

Synonym created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_tid number;
  3  begin
  4    insert into scott_tablesample (description) values ('XY')
  5    returning tid into l_tid;
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Returned value = ' || l_tid);
  7  end;
  8  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22816: unsupported feature with RETURNING clause
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

---

What to do? Nothing much, regarding the `returning` clause. If you recreated the table so that the ID isn't generated always (i.e. you're allowed to insert your own values):

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> drop table tablesample;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table tablesample
  2    (description varchar2(2),
  3     tid number generated by default on null as identity
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tablesample(description) values ('AB');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From tablesample;

DE        TID
-- ----------
AB          1
```

Find which sequence is being used for the identity column:

```
SQL> select data_default from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLESAMPLE';

DATA_DEFAULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"MIKE"."ISEQ$$_99985".nextval
```

Connected as `scott`, create a synonym to the sequence and use it in `insert` statement:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create synonym mike_seq for iseq$$_99985@dbl_mike;

Synonym created.
```

Insert:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_seq number;
  3  begin
  4    l_seq := mike_seq.nextval;
  5    insert into tablesample@dbl_mike (description, tid)
  6      values ('MN', l_seq);
  7    dbms_output.put_line('TID = ' || l_seq);
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tablesample@dbl_mike;

DE        TID
-- ----------
MN          2              --> here it is
AB          1

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If you want to get sequence name used for identity column, query

```
SQL> select sequence_name
  2  from user_tab_identity_cols
  3  where table_name = 'TABLESAMPLE';

SEQUENCE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISEQ$$_99985

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT #2]**

If you want to use sequence name in PL/SQL procedure, you'll need **dynamic SQL**. Apart from that, `currval` won't work if sequence hasn't been initialized yet in this session:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_seq_name varchar2(20);
  3    v_str      varchar2(200);
  4    v_val      number;
  5  begin
  6    select sequence_name
  7    into v_seq_name
  8    from user_tab_identity_cols@dbl_mike
  9    where table_name = 'TABLESAMPLE';
 10
 11    v_str := 'select ' || v_seq_name || '.currval@dbl_mike from dual';
 12    execute immediate v_str into v_val;
 13    dbms_output.put_line('Value = ' || v_val);
 14  end;
 15  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08002: sequence ISEQ$$_99985.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session
ORA-02063: preceding line from DBL_MIKE
ORA-06512: at line 12
```

Therefore, use `nextval`:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_seq_name varchar2(20);
  3    v_str      varchar2(200);
  4    v_val      number;
  5  begin
  6    select sequence_name
  7    into v_seq_name
  8    from user_tab_identity_cols@dbl_mike
  9    where table_name = 'TABLESAMPLE';
 10
 11    v_str := 'select ' || v_seq_name || '.nextval@dbl_mike from dual';
 12    execute immediate v_str into v_val;
 13    dbms_output.put_line('Value = ' || v_val);
 14  end;
 15  /
Value = 7

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: this is good. Can i get only the seq name here in this select data_default from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLESAMPLE'; ....that means i need to extract only SEQ$$_99985. Because after insert i can get the currval using seq name

Comment: Query USER_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS (see example in edited answer).

Comment: DECLARE v_seq_name VARCHAR2(20);
      BEGIN
      select sequence_name INTO v_seq_name from user_tab_identity_cols@dblink1  where table_name = 'table1';
      select v_seq_name.currval@dblink1 into v_rid_return from dual; 
        END;

Comment: i tried to get the sequence name in a variable and using that variable i tried to get the currval ... but this doesnt work for me

Comment: You'll need **dynamic SQL**; see EDIT #2 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As error says, it is not supported. However, you may use `dbms_sql` package over DB link to execute remote SQL code.

> ```
> SQL> declare
>   2      l_id int;
>   3      l_value constant int := 100;
>   4  begin
>   5      insert into t@test2_dblink(val)
>   6      values(l_value)
>   7      returning id into l_id;
>   8  
>   9      dbms_output.put_line(l_id);
>  10  end;
>  11  /
>
> Error starting at line : 5 in command -
> declare
>     l_id int;
>     l_value constant int := 100;
> begin
>     insert into t@test2_dblink(val)
>     values(l_value)
>     returning id into l_id;
>
>     dbms_output.put_line(l_id);
> end;
> Error report -
> ORA-22816: с фразой RETURNING это средство не поддерживается
> ORA-06512: на  line 5
> 22816. 00000 -  "unsupported feature with RETURNING clause"
> *Cause:    RETURNING clause is currently not supported for object type
>            columns, LONG columns, remote tables, INSERT with subquery,
>            and INSTEAD OF Triggers.
> *Action:   Use separate select statement to get the values.
> ```

Table is empty.

> ```
> SQL> select *
>   2  from t@test2_dblink
>   3  /
>
> 0 rows selected.
> ```

> ```
> SQL> declare
>   2      l_id int;
>   3      l_value constant int := 100;
>   4      l_cursor int;
>   5      l_stmt varchar2(1000);
>   6      l_rowcount int;
>   7  begin
>   8      l_stmt := q'{insert into t(val)
>   9      values(:value)
>  10      returning id into :id}';
>  11  
>  12      l_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor@test2_dblink();
>  13      dbms_sql.parse@test2_dblink(l_cursor, l_stmt, dbms_sql.native);
>  14  
>  15      dbms_sql.bind_variable@test2_dblink(l_cursor, 'value', l_value);
>  16      dbms_sql.bind_variable@test2_dblink(l_cursor, 'id', l_id);
>  17      l_rowcount := dbms_sql.execute@test2_dblink(l_cursor);
>  18      dbms_sql.variable_value@test2_dblink(l_cursor, 'id', l_id);
>  19      dbms_sql.close_cursor@test2_dblink(l_cursor);
>  20  
>  21  
>  22      dbms_output.put_line('ID is: ' || l_id);
>  23      commit;
>  24  end;
>  25  /
>
> ID is: 3
>
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
> ```

Value was inserted successfully.

> ```
> SQL> select *
>   2  from t@test2_dblink
>   3  /
>
>         ID        VAL
> ---------- ----------
>          3        100
>
> 1 row selected.
> ```